# Should the [arbitrary] tag be burninated?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Using a tag like [arbitrary](/questions/tagged/arbitrary) itself suggests that the tag has been chosen rather *arbitrarily*.  As of now, there are 48 questions with the tag.

Although it might not be tough to guess, the usage of the tag in question doesn't exhibit any pattern.  It's used in the context of:

- arbitrary precision numbers
- arbitrary file upload
- arbitrary point
- arbitrary line
- arbitrary dimensional array
- arbitrary sampling
- arbitrary variables
- arbitrary number of words
- arbitrary size
- arbitrary value
- arbitrary interaction
- arbitrary increment
- arbitrary resources
- arbitrary position
- arbitrary query
- arbitrary function
- ... (and the list goes on)

Should we burninate [arbitrary](/questions/tagged/arbitrary)?  Could we also blacklist it?

---

**UPDATE:** It looks like that the tag has been removed from all the 48 questions.  As of now, there isn't a single [arbitrary](/questions/tagged/arbitrary) question!

Comment: Oh dear... Burn! *Burn!* ***Burn!!!***

Comment: How arbitrary can arbitrary be?

Comment: That would be a rather arbitrary decision.

Comment: HERE I ARBITRARILY CALL UPON THE POWERS OF TROGDOR THE ALMIGHTY! Let the arbitrary burnination begin! :-)

Comment: A downnvote almost 5 months later.  How _arbitrary_!